# Why is the autorun information by the startup shortcut created by InstallSheild incorrect?

Tags: installation, installshield, startup

I have an InstallShield 2013 project that puts a shortcut into the Startup folder. When I run the installer, the shortcut is placed correctly and seems to have the correct path information. All seems well.

Then I look at the startup information provided by the windows task manager. The startup entry reads.
Name: InstallShield
Publisher: Flexera Software LLC

When using the right click "Open File Location", the path opened is not the path of the generated shortcut. Instead, it is C:\Windows\Installer{GUID}\NewShortcut2_{HexString}.exe

Why is this happening, and how do I change it?

Edit: The testing has been done on a windows 8.1 system.

Comment: I am seeing this on Windows 10 as well, and it is fairly obvious in the Task Manager Startup tab.  Just as the OP pointed out, the properties of the auto-generated exe file have Flexera's info instead of matching the info of the corresponding executable.

Comment: Hello, I am also facing the Same issue, So please give the proper solution if you have. I have tried from since last 3 to 4 days but all in vain, so pls guy's help me....@BTJ

Answer (score 1):

Per the requirements of the [Icon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369210.aspx) table (see the Remarks section), InstallShield creates an exe format file that includes the icon for your shortcut. This is the file placed in the location you mention above. However it is not the target of the shortcut, so I do not understand why Windows is indicating this. I don't think InstallShield offers any ways to tweak how it builds the Icon table, unless it does things differently for advertised and non-advertised shortcuts.

(BTW, I suspect this behavior is specific to certain versions of Windows, so it may be worth editing that into your question.)

Comment: Hello, I am also facing the Same issue, So please give the proper solution if you have. I have tried from since last 3 to 4 days but all in vain, so pls guy's help me....@michael urman